# How to export all Bash functions in a file in one line?

Tags: bash, bash-functions

In Ubuntu 16.04 I have a Bash file containing a few different functions for automating various common tasks on my system.

I have sourced that file in `bashrc` so I could comfortably call each function from anywhere in the terminal in time of need, hence we can say that "the functions themselves are sourced".

Sometimes I need to use one of these sourced functions **from inside a script**, and I need to [prim](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/priming) this action with:

```
export -f myFunc_0 myFunc_1 myFunc_2 ...
```

<sub>otherwise, I won't be able to use these functions.</sub>

---

How could I do that priming to **all** functions in the file, without noting specific functions?

Comment: I know you already know that this is a bad approach, but I'm noting it here explicitly for any future readers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use `set -a` either in your `.bashrc` or within the function file itself it will mark all functions to be exported.

> [4.3.1 The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)
>
> -a
>
> Each variable or function that is created or modified is given the export attribute and marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands.

This may cause some undesirable results if you are setting variables that you don't want exported, but you could add something like this to your `.bashrc`:

```
set -a
source ~/my_funcs
set +a
```

Comment: ok, but wouldn't calling `set +a` override the sourcing script if the sourcing script wanted it to be `set -a`, seems like not a good solution

Comment: depends from which context you call `set +a`, but it could affect shell if `set -a` was actually desired. Basically what I am saying is only call `set +a` if that was already set.

Answer (score 8):

What you should really do is source the file containing the functions inside the script itself, that way it won’t be context-dependent (or rather, it will be less context-dependent).

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what this means, can you provide a short example? thx

Answer (score 7):

You could try something like:

```
declare -fx $(bash -c 'source /path/to/my-file &> /dev/null; compgen -A function')
```

Since you want to export only functions from the file, sourcing it in a new instance of bash and then using `compgen -A function` will list names of all the functions defined in that file (and previously exported functions too, but that shouldn't be a problem here). Then you can use the output of that with `export -f` or `declare -fx` to export those functions.

As you're sourcing the file in your bashrc, re-sourcing it probably won't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at BASH_ENV

```
INVOCATION
          When bash is started non-interactively, to  run  a  shell script,  for
          example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
          its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the  name
          of  a  file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following com‐
          mand were executed:
          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
          but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the  file‐
          name.

  BASH_ENV
          If  this parameter is set when bash is executing a shell script,
          its value is interpreted as a filename  containing  commands  to
          initialize the shell, as in ~/.bashrc.  The value of BASH_ENV is
          subjected to  parameter  expansion,  command  substitution,  and
          arithmetic  expansion  before  being  interpreted as a filename.
          PATH is not used to search for the resultant filename.
```

When bash execute a shell script non-interactively .bashrc is not read and the function file are not sourced.
If BASH_ENV is set to the name of the function file, this file is read and executed like said in INVOCATION.
So no need to source the function file in each shell script which use the function.

**Example to illustrate :**

Not Ubuntu but debian-linux 4.14.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.17-1 (2018-02-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux with Xfce 4.12

Create a file of functions in your `$HOME`

> cat mesfuncbash

```
piste ()
{
echo $0 >> ~/lapiste
date >> ~/lapiste
}
```

Create a script which use the function

> cat lescript

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
. ~/mesfuncbash
piste
echo fin
```

here the script source the function file

Create a laucher to `lescript` on the `Desktop`

No need of terminal

execute it.

The file `~/lapiste` is updated.

Now remove `. ~/mesfuncbash` from `lescript`

execute it

The file `~/lapiste` is not updated.

If you run `lescript` on a terminal

Bash tell you :

```
line 3: piste: command not found
```

Now you must set `BASH_ENV` to the name of the function file.

In debian with xfce, `.profile` is not read at startup so you can't use it to set `BASH_ENV`.

You must create a file `.xsessionrc` in your `$HOME`.

> cat .xsessionrc

```
export BASH_ENV="$HOME/mesfuncbash"
```

logout and login, this way `.xsessionrc` is read at startup

Now, you can execute the laucher on the Desktop
and the file `~/lapiste` is updated.

Comment: Hi ctac_. I think you should add more markup to your question. Please consider that.

Comment: @user9303970 sorry, I don't understand 'add more markup to your question'. Do you want I add more explain ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant markdown, not markup. That is to ask, please add more formatting. There are some places you wrote code or paths and these are best to be formatted with the text-editor, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `set` appears to be sorted favorably for extracting all defined functions.  It starts with variables and then shows functions, soes:

```
set |awk '/^[^=()]*\(\)/ {functions=1} functions' > functions.sh
```

This looks for the first non-assignment (an occurrence of `()` before the first `=`) and then says that's okay to print. The second awk stanza uses the default print action when the variable `functions` is true.  The output is saved in `functions.sh`, which can then be sourced elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Just use the `env` command:

```
env > /path/to/file
```

Comment: how is this supposed to work? explanation?