# export bash function inline

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have this:

```
foo(){
   install_ores_gitflow;
   command foo "$@"
}

export -f foo;
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
export foo(){
   install_ores_gitflow;
   command foo "$@"
}
```

but that syntax is not correct.

One technique I found is this:
[How to export all Bash functions in a file in one line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428175/how-to-export-all-bash-functions-in-a-file-in-one-line)

so that means I could do this:

```
set -a;

foo(){
  install_ores_gitflow;
  command foo "$@"
}

set +a;
```

but I don't like that solution because the sourcing script could have `set -a` which means my script would override that which is very bad.

Comment: What specifically is wrong with `export -f foo`?

Comment: bash is a dynamic language, I will refactor the name of the bash function, delete a bash function, etc, and forget to change the export lines.

Comment: Why do you like to do this? Exported functions are seen as a security risk and intentionally not part of POSIX. The clean way is to put the definitions into the interactive startup script or to let scripts source a file with the related definitions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a nasty hack, but at least it allows you to puts the `export` command *above* the function definition where it's easier to see it.

```
# a function to create a dummy function and export it
export_function() { eval "function $1 { :; }; export -f $1"; }

# then

export_function foo
foo() { echo "here is the *real* function"; }
```

Comment: I think I got it, see my answer, using the $SHELLOPTS env var

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check the `-a` option's status with e.g. `echo $-`, so no action needed if it is set?

Comment: that might work, can you give an example of that in full? A problem with that though is in many cases we don't want to export all bash functions.

Comment: how do I check if a is set with `echo $-`?

Comment: I think I got it, see my answer, using the $SHELLOPTS env var

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I think this is a sane and reliable way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! "$SHELLOPTS" =~ "allexport" ]]; then
    set -a;
    all_export=nope;
fi


ores_git_merge_with_integration(){
   install_ores_gitflow;
   command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"
}

ores_git_tools(){
   install_ores_gitflow;
   command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"
}


if [ "$all_export" == "nope" ]; then
  set +a;
fi
```

in your bash script, potentially could group all your functions to be exported and surround them with the set -a / set + commands.

The purpose of checking the `$SHELLOPTS` env var is to see if set -a was not on, and if it wasn't, we need to turn it off when we are done.